# How to redirect user after send form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();

        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<html><head>");
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("</head><body onload=\"document.{0}.submit()\">", "pay"));
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("</head><body>"));
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<form name=\"{0}\" method=\"{1}\" action=\"{2}\" >", "pay", "post", payURL));
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<input name=\"MERCHANT\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"{0}\">", merchant));
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</form>");
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</body></html>");
              System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

User send form and i want redirect users from payURL

Comment: If you're using MVC everything you're doing here is wrong. Go through the tutorials at http://www.asp.net/mvc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Response.Redirect("Redirectpage.aspx");`